# React Native Android - custom BroadcastReceiver/Service is being killed after some hours

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app using React Native which requires a service that detects missed calls and sends that on the server and then shows a notification in phone status bar.

I decided to write my own extension that will handle that because I didn't found any node module that will be sufficient for my needs. Unfortunately, service is being killed after some hours and I can't handle with that. Basically, I'm JavaScript developer and native code in Java is for me like a black hole so I'll be very grateful for any help.

The app is using Headless JS for sending data to the server, basically all extension was based on articles:

- http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/detect-missed-call-in-android.html
- https://codeburst.io/simple-android-call-recorder-in-react-native-headlessjs-task-614bcc56efc4

I've found some similar topics:

- [Android service process being killed after hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286780/android-service-process-being-killed-after-hours)
- https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

And tried to follow the instructions described there, but all of these solutions are related only with native code without using React Native and Headless JS so I don't know if that solutions will be ok for app that using React Native or probably (for sure) I'm doing something wrong.

Here is my AndroidManifest part responsible for Service and BroadcastReceiver:

```
(...)
<service android:name="com.app.service.CallLogService" />
<receiver android:name="com.app.receiver.CallLogReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
(...)
```

My CallLogService class:

```
package com.app.service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class CallLogService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {

    @Nullable
    protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "CallLog",
            extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : null,
            5000,
            true
        );
    }
}
```

My CallLogReceiver class:

```
package com.app.receiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import com.app.service.CallLogService;
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService;

public final class CallLogReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        (...)

        callerPhoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, CallLogService.class);

        callIntent.putExtra("phone_number", callerPhoneNumber);
        context.startService(callIntent);
        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);

    }
}
```

I'm using React Native 0.50.3

At the end I have an additional question. I noticed that after restart phone the service is also killed. How can I prevent such situation too?

---

**Edit:**
I noticed that if app is in background then after sending request the response is not recorded.

But after firing a new request the application is getting response from previous request. I'm using `axios` for doing **ajax**.

Eg.

```
let callAjax = function(counter){
    console.log('Request ' + counter);

    axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
    .then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Response ' + counter);
    })
};

callAjax(1);
setTimeout(() => {
    callAjax(2);
}, 5000);
```

When app is in background then I have:

`Request 1`

After 5 sec

`Response 1 Request 2`

When app is in foreground then everything is ok:

`Request 1 Response 1`

After 5 sec

`Request 2 Response 2`